# Is there an algorithm polynomial in dimension of space and number of points for the Minimum Enclosing Ball?

Tags: clustering, minimax

Let $C_1, ..., C_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ Is there a polynomial algorithm in $n,m$ which finds the Minimum Enclosing Ball (MEB) for these points?

### My research

I see mentions of algorithms like Megido, Waltz etc. which are known to solve the problem in linear time in $m$, the number of points, but these seem to be exponential in $n$.

Comment: are you taking Euclidean distances?

Comment: There are approximation algorithms based on coresets with polynomial dimension, and there are algorithms with good practical performance on high-dimensional input. But I'm not aware of any exact algorithms with polynomial dependence on the dimension. Are you more interested in theoretical results, or practical performance?

Comment: @inuyashaYagami yes, Euclidean distance!

Comment: @discreteLizard I am interested in theoretical results! What should be understood by core sets with polynomial dimension? A subset of the points? I would guess that $m$ should be anyway a polynomial w.r.t $n$, otherwise the problem is not approachable in high dimension !

Comment: @CMarius I meant that there are approximation algorithms that use small [coresets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreset) and have a running time with polynomial dependency on the dimension $n$ (which is usually called $d$ in the literature). For example, [Kumar, P., Mitchell, J. S., & Yildirim, E. A. (2003). _Approximate minimum enclosing balls in high dimensions using core-sets._] give a $(1+\varepsilon)$-approximation algorithm that runs in $O(mn/\varepsilon +(1/\varepsilon)^{4.5}\log (1/\varepsilon))$ time for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: As for the relation between $m$ and $n$, we may assume $n\leq m$: the dimension of the point set is at most $m$, so we can always change the basis to a vector space of dimension $m$. I'm not sure what you mean by the problem not being approachable when $m$ is not a polynomial function of $n$, can you clarify?

Comment: @discretelizard Well, for instance if $m = 2^n$ then even an algorithm linear in $m$ is still un-useful for a large $n$. Thank you for the reference!